# C#/WPF: Why is tab not focusing properly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, collectionviewsource

I have a tab control

```
<TabControl Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
```

That is bound to `Tabs` in the `ViewModel`. I also used `CollectionViewSource` to focus tabs

```
protected ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> _tabs;
protected ICollectionView _tabsViewSource;

public ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> Tabs
{
    get { return _tabs; }
}
public void OnTabsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count > 0)
        foreach (TabViewModel tab in e.NewItems)
        {
            tab.CloseRequested += OnCloseRequested;
            _tabsViewSource.MoveCurrentTo(tab); // focus newly created tab
        }
    if (e.OldItems != null && e.OldItems.Count > 0)
        foreach (TabViewModel tab in e.OldItems)
            tab.CloseRequested -= OnCloseRequested;
}
```

When I have more that 1 tab, when I create new Tabs, tabs are focused properly

[image]

when there are no tabs, new tabs don't seem to be focused properly. notice the tab header

[image]

how might I fix this? or what is causing this behavior? the text box (tab content) is shown but the header don't render like its selected

### UPDATE

It works with a fresh file/project ... hmm ... must be some related code ... I might redo that part ...

Comment: Can you tell us how far the code goes when there are no tabs, does it hit the focus line?

Comment: @kyndigs, what do you mean by how far the code goes? do you mean `_tabsViewSource.MoveCurrentTo(tab)`. That code only gets run when new tabs are created to focus them? or thats what they should do.

Answer (score 1):

`IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` has no meaning unless you bind your `TabControl.ItemsSource` to an `ICollectionView`.

I can't tell if changing your binding from ObservableCollection to ICollectionView will solve your problem, but that is how I have setup my databound tabcontrol.

An alternative could be to expose a new property

```
public TabViewModel CurrentTabViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return _tabs.CurrentItem as TabViewModel:
    }
    set
    {
        _tabs.MoveCurrentTo(value);
    }
}
```

and bind TabControl's `SelectedItem` to `CurrentTabViewModel`

```
<TabControl SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentTabViewModel}" ... />
```

Comment: I tried binding to the `ObservableCollection` and `ICollectionView` but both gave the same result, I also tried binding to `CurrentTabViewModel` and it still failed. any idea whats with that rendering? the text box shows correctly but not the header

Comment: Any idea if its just a rendering bug? it only occurs at the start or when the tab control has no tabs and i add 1

Answer (score 0):

Without the code, that initializes the single-tab-collection, it's just guessing.
A Workaround for you would be setting SelectedIndex of the tabView = 0 -> first tab is selected initially.

```
<TabControl Height="Auto" 
  Grid.Row="1" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" 
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
  SelectedIndex="0">
```

Comment: This seem to work only at the start, when I close all tabs and add one, i get the same problem. subsequent tabs rendered correctly